# Run scala script from shell script

Tags: scala, shell, classpath

I have a Scala project that contains both Scala classes/objects as well as scripts. I am trying to run the scripts (that use the classes/objects to perform various actions) from command line. The way I am looking to do this is to create a shell that would be passed as argument the name of the script, as well as the arguments that the script itself takes.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
runner.sh -> script I am trying to implement to run the Scala scripts
bin/ -> script I am trying to implement to run the Scala scripts
lib/ -> -> rest of scala project, packed as multiple jars
```

I am currently creating a variable `LIB_CLASSPATH` in the shell script that contains the contents of the `lib/` folder and I am trying to run my scrips as follows:

```
java -cp $LIB_CLASSPATH ./bin/<name_of_script.scala> <parameters of the script>
```

I always get back the same error:

```
Could not find or load main class: ..lib/<name of jar> 
-- <name of jar> is actually the first jar in the lib/ folder
```

I could use some guidance :)

### Thanks

Comment: You seem to be passing to `java` a script of Scala source. It doesn't know what to do with it. Either use `scala` instead of `java`, or compile your script first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Ammonite`](https://ammonite.io/) (written by @lihaoyi).

It's a combination of a better Scala REPL, Shell, OPs library, and **Script runner**.
See the docs here - https://ammonite.io/

10 min talk showing how is it better for scripting & shell - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk2-ZsQU358

I think it can be a good starting point as well. Talk was given by me :)

Comment: Can't use Ammonite, unfortunately

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea why?

Comment: Not firm approved

Comment: Above Ammonite link is no more valid

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sbt native packager. See:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

You add this line to build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

And define a main class:

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("org.shapelogic.sc.javafx.ViewGui")
```

To run:

```
sbt stage
```

It create startup script located in a place like this:

```
target/universal/stage/bin/shapelogic
```

Here is an example of how I used the script:

```
target/universal/stage/bin/shapelogic -- -i image/440px-Lenna.png
```

If you want to run another class you can do this:

```
target/universal/stage/bin/shapelogic -main "org.shapelogic.sc.script.Threshold" -- i image/440px-Lenna.png
```

Comment: I cannot use sbt, unfortunately

Comment: You could try to take a look at the start script that sbt native packager builds and make a simplified version.

Comment: sbt native packager creates a little bash script that declares the needed variables:
They call your LIB_CLASSPATH for app_classpath
Here is the start of that:

declare  -r app_classpath="$lib_dir/org.shapelogic.sc.shapelogic-0.4.1.jar:$lib_dir/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:...

Comment: I created a Gist with the whole bash startup script:

https://gist.github.com/sami-badawi/82c303502d761db12aec11bb76d1e67d

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will do what you want.  It's based on a script I use, but stripped down for clarity:

```
#!/bin/bash

# copies of or symlinks to all required jar files
# must be in one of the directories referenced by CP

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "usage: ${0##*} <scala-script-path>" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

REQUIRED_JAR_DIRECTORIES=(
"/usr/local/olib/*"
"/usr/local/jlib/*"
)
CP=$(echo "${REQUIRED_JAR_DIRECTORIES[@]}" | tr ' ' ':')
case `uname` in
CYGWIN*)
  CP=`cygpath -p -w "$CP"`
  ;;
esac
scala -deprecation -feature -classpath "$CP" "$@"
```

The easiest way to use this script is to place it in your PATH, and then add the following hash-bang line to the top of your scala script.  Assuming you call this script 'scalaRunner', here's a standalone working scala script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalaRunner

println("Hello World!")
```

Here's one that's slightly more elaborate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalaRunner

if( args.isEmpty ){
  printf("usage: <arg1> [<arg2> ..]\n")
  sys.exit(1)
}
for( (arg,i) <- args.zipWithIndex ){
  printf("arg %d: %s\n",i,arg)
}
```

If you import anything, just make sure all required jars are in the REQUIRED_JAR_DIRECTORIES.

In practice, you may want something more flexible than this script, especially with regard to specifying where required jars reside.