# What is the recommended idiom for creating a new file in the same directory as another with better.files?

Tags: scala, scripting, idioms

I'm enjoying the "`better.files`" library in my scala scripts, and one of the common operations (for me) is to create a new file in the same directory as an existing file.   My first attempt turns out to be rather verbose and ugly, so I'm wondering if there's a better idiom.

To be specific, here's a bash script that's the equivalent of what I'm wanting to do in scala:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC="$HOME/Downloads/some-file.txt"
SRCDIR=$(dirname "$SRC")
DST="$SRCDIR/another-file.txt"
echo "hello!" > "$DST"
```

In order to accomplish the same thing using the `better.files` library, here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalaRunner

import better.files._
import better.files.Dsl._
import java.io.{File => JFile}

val SRC = File.home/"Downloads"/"some-file.txt"
val SRCDIR = SRC.parent
val DST = new JFile(SRCDIR.toJava,"another-file.txt").toScala
DST.overwrite("hello!\n")
```

It's almost as concise and readable as the bash script, although it would be nice if conversions to and from java.io.File could be hidden.    Of course I can always create implicit converters to do just that, but maybe there's a better alternative.

Although there's nothing wrong with explicit conversions, I'm mostly wanting to avoid doing this if there's already a less verbose way to do the equivalent.

For anyone wanting to experiment, both of the above scripts should be executable as-is, assuming the `$SRC` file already exists, etc.  A working '`scalaRunner`' script can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361608/666886

It assumes that the better-files jar resides in your classpath, as described in the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
val src = File.home/"Downloads"/"betterfiles" / "document.jpg"
val srcDir = src.parent
val dst: File = srcDir.createChild("another-file.txt")
dst.overwrite("hello!\n")
```